# Trouble binding an inner repeater to a grouped list of grouped lists

Tags: c#, list, datasource, repeater

I have the following object:

```
var years = articles.GroupBy(a => a.Year).Select(yearGroup => new
{
    Year = yearGroup.Key,
    PerMonth = yearGroup.GroupBy(a => a.Month).Select(monthGroup => new
    {
        Month = monthGroup.Key,
        Articles = monthGroup.ToList()
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();

Repeater1.DataSource = years;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

I'm trying to display this as follows:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="yearGroup">
            <h1 class="yearHeading"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Year") %></h1>
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PerMonth")%>'>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="monthGroup">
                        <h3 class="monthHeading"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Month") %></h3>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" runat="server" DataSource="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Articles") %>">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <h1>Article title</h1>
                                <%--<div class="Article">
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title") %>
                                </div>--%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Everything works up until the final repeater. When I delete `Repeater3` it works, but when I put in the final repeater, I get an error, for some reason it doesn't like

```
DataSource="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Articles") %>
```

My Event Viewer says

> The server tag is not well formed.

Answer (score 0):

Try exchanging the " " around the server tag for ' ' instead.

So that:

```
"<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Articles") %>"
```

becomes:

```
'<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Articles") %>'
```